# How to debug node process that exits unexpectedly with code 1, but no apparent error message, and unpredictably

Tags: node.js, debugging, memory-management, v8, vscode-debugger

I already have handlers for `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection` and I am thinking that this isn't a js error at all, as it happens at several different points in the code, and other times does not occur. I am thinking that it could be memory related and there is some evidence to suggest this is the case, however, it doesn't behave the same as with an out of memory exception that I have purposely produced for the purpose of comparison.

The process is not using an excessive or growing amount of memory according to tooling, and when it has happened most of the memory has been consumed by other processes.

Comment: Well, is it possible the process is calling `process.exit()`? 

Comment: Not really, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is it possible that the nodejs process just exits naturally because there are no open sockets, no active timers, nothing active that can cause a future event that is being listened for, etc...  If the refcnt of things that keep nodejs alive goes to zero, it will just exit on its own.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, because it is in the middle of a job, which is doing a lot of things and   exits eg in the middle of a loop, with code 1.

Comment: There are other events that could be triggered on process: `exit`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `SIGTERM`. I'd recommend adding a listener on those just in case. Apart from that, I have no idea...

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it *might* be a bug in Node or a native module (if you're using any), but without further data, it's hard to be sure of anything.

Things you could try:

- Run Node from a terminal and watch its output ("`stdout`"). (There may well not be any.)
- Get a Debug build of Node, and watch its `stdout`. (It may or may not print more.)
- Run that Debug build of Node in a debugger, and when it crashes, get a stack trace. (You could also try that with a regular Release build, but I don't know if such builds include "symbols"; if they don't, then the stack trace will be useless.)
- Try to find a repro case and make that available for other people to investigate.
- Update (or, as a last resort, downgrade) Node and hope that the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to solve a similar issue in my CI/CD pipeline (Jenkins) after struggling some time, it was all related to the memory.

**TLDR:** use `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096` according to your memory available

And for the context because I think it's important:

Randomly my builds were failing with the following logs, it was not mentioning what was causing the "exit code 1"... I tried to log everything I could, also to enable "--verbose" for what I could... but it was always ending this way:

```
...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

*Environment: a Vue project using as command `vue-cli-service build` and so as plugin `webpack`, tested with Node v12 and Node v16 but no difference (except with v16 the error was more frequent)*

The CI/CD worker (Jenkins) was in a Kubernetes environment and it had some resource limitations so I suspect Node.js using more than expected and making the program crash with no logs. What is weird is:

- Usually when a container/pod in Kubernetes is killed due to memory issue an event is recorded ("OOM: killed...")
- If the Node.js has terminated itself due to exceeding the "--max-old-space-size" it should have notified me...

Path to the solution:

1. I used `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=1024` at start and it was working better, but it failed one time with an error that is explicit: I restricted too much the memory.

```
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit

<--- Last few GCs --->

[807:0x4b02670]   205629 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 994.4 (1016.4) -> 993.7 (1017.2) MB, 1092.9 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.201, current mu = 0.039) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[807:0x4b02670]   207056 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 996.2 (1018.5) -> 994.6 (1018.1) MB, 1419.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.102, current mu = 0.005) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0xcf8dde v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0xcf9157 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0xeb09f5  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0xec06bd v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0xec33be v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0xe848fa v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x11fd646 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x15f20b9  [/usr/local/bin/node]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
make: *** [Makefile:21: build-dev] Error 1
```

2. I tried to listen for termination/error events but nothing was logged:

```js
const events = ['SIGTERM', 'SIGINT', 'beforeExit', 'rejectionHandled', 'uncaughtException', 'exit'];

events.forEach((eventName) => {
  console.log('listening on ', eventName);
  process.on(eventName, (...args) => {
    console.log('event ' + eventName + ' was called with args : ' + args.join(','));

    // Just for test to exit the pipeline ASAP
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

*(I set this in my `vue.config.js` but it could be in your `webpack.config.js` or so, at the top.*

3. I removed the environment variable and tried in my CI/CD `node -e "console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics())"` and I saw `heap_size_limit: 1660944384` which means around 1.5GB of memory **by default**
4. Since I had enough memory on the node I set it the `heap_size_limit` to 4GB (while increasing the Kubernetes pod memory limit) and **it's working great**
5. ... I'm really sad to have lose so much time on it. The final conclusion is it seems related to the memory and it's likely something in the stack is not reporting the failure of memory. In my case only when **specifying** a little `--max-old-space-size` was producing the memory error (the default was not), and if I adjust the value correctly it makes it working...

Hope this helps (sorry for the big context, it may help people debug on their side) :)

*BONUS: during my investigation I noted some additional parameters that could help to debug/investigate `--optimize-for-size`, `--huge-max-old-generation-size`, `--no-huge-max-old-generation-size` (please read the docs for more information)*

*NOTE: my logs say all the time `Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit` due to the plugin `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin` that parses TypeScript with another worker.*